# Having a vertical line between two child divs in a parent div and making vertical line touching base of parent div even if parent div got a scroll

Tags: html, css

I think this may be a old question but I am difficult to find a answer.
I have one parent div and two child divs in it using display:inline block ( for tabular structure.

I want to have a vertical line between two child divs so i added another child div as divider div.

The way it should work is - if any child div has more content then there should be vertical scroll bar in parent div.

Now the issue i am having is - when i am getting a scroll bar in parent the divider div is not touching the bottom border of parent div. there is a gap. I need it to be touched to bottom all the time.

HTML

```css
.container {
  border:1px solid red;
  display:block;
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  overflow-y:auto;
  position:relative;
  max-height:400px;
}
.column {
  width:49%;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  position:relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  }
  .divider{
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    border-left:1px solid red;
 height:100%;
 display:inline-block;
 max-height:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="column">
  Test Test Test Test 
  Test Test Test Test 
  Test Test Test Test 
  Test Test Test Test 
 </div>
 <div class="divider">
 
 </div>
 <div class="column">
  Test
 </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be much appreciated...

Comment: why don't you use a table or flexbox?

Comment: I wanted to achieve using div.. I used display:table and display:table-cell but those are not working in IE8..

Answer (score 1):

Well, everything it's working fine. basically you give the `divider` a 100% height, and that means 100% height of his parent which is set to 400px. That div can't understand that's there's content overflowing in the `column` unless you yo use javascript (or jquery) to know previously the real height of the `column` and set that height to your "divider".

What I can see as the best and fastest fix... why don't you use border-right insteed of using a div? **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/j0k6f0by/)**

```
.column {

  border-right:1px solid red;
}
```

**Edited:** Well, as you have commented that your right column may have a higher height that the left one... you could also give your right column a `border-left` however that could be messy if you dont use `border-box`on your divs (which I do recomend you to get use for every single project. if you not familiar with it here you have it very well explained: https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/).

Then after adding border-box to your containers, you can easily add the `border-left` to the right one, move it 1px (or whatever width you want to set up) to the left with margin and both borders will overlap.

Oh, and I have changed the `inline-block` to float insteed as `inline-block` elements always leave a little space between them and obviously you don't want that space in this example.

**[updated FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/j0k6f0by/1/)**

**New edit:** now you have the left column at 50% and the right is 50% -1px. Probably it will never matter as no user will probably notice, but if you are a perfectionist insteed of giving your right column a 50% width you may use css3 option and use:

```
width: calc(50% + 1px);
```

**[perfectionist fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/j0k6f0by/2/)**

Comment: I tried this. For our requirement, parent div needs to have fixed height. and if i have border-right and if right side div has more content then I am running into same problem.

Comment: I edited a few times my answer in case it may help you